# Regex with at least one of two options but in sequence

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regex (for use in a Java Pattern) that will match strings that possibly have a letter that is possibly followed by a space then number, but must have at least one of them. For example, the following strings should be matched:

- "a 5"
- "b 9"
- " 8"

However, it should not match an empty string ("").

Furthermore, I would like to make each of the components part a named capture group.

The following works, but allows the empty string.

```
"(?<let>\\p{Alpha})?( (?<num>\\p{Digit}))?"
```

Comment: You want to match a single letter also e.g. `p` ?

Comment: you want to match space?

Comment: Yes, I want to match just a single letter but no, a single space shouldn't match.

Comment: Thanks to those of you who introduced me to lookahead in your answers. That is really going to help me with regexes in the future!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ensure that there is at least one of them, you can use lookahead `(?=\\p{Alpha}| \\p{Digit})` at the beginning:

```
"(?=\\p{Alpha}| \\p{Digit})(?<let>\\p{Alpha})?( (?<num>\\p{Digit}))?"
```

In general, to avoid empty strings you can use `(?=.)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookahead to avoid empty input and keep your regex as:

```
^(?!$)(?<let>\p{L})?(?:\h+(?<num>\p{N}))?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JZWOdV/1)

`(?!$)` is negative lookahead to fail the match for empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve problem with:

```
([a-z]? \d)|([a-z] \d?)
```

You can see this code that covers your test cases in demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/mSP6kY/7). You can see this code in demo here. This is very basic regular expression knowledge, you should definitely learn more about regular expressions, there are bunch of good tutorials on web (e.g this one).

Comment: This won't match just letters (e.g. "a").

Comment: Thanks for feedback,  I misunderstood. I've updated answer :)

Comment: Yes, I knew about that regex, but it didn't fully solve my problem. The problem is that I wanted named capture groups and I wanted the letter to always have the same capture group name `let` and the digit to have the group name `num`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use | for or, then simply repeat "any pattern" to match everything like this.

```
((?<let>[A-z])|(?<num>\d)\s*)+
```

That lets you match any number of named patterns in any order.